# ERROR 1: Failed to write .vrt file in FlushCache()

Tags: gdal, gdalbuildvrt

I'm trying to build .vrt from georeferenced DEM files from Photoscan.

`gdalbuildvrt global_dem.vrt dem*.tif`

It was working on Ubuntu 12.04(`GDAL 1.10.0, released 2013/04/24`), but now it fails on Ubuntu 14.04 (`GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25`)

`ERROR 1: Failed to write .vrt file in FlushCache().`

How to fix it?

Comment: Had the same error. For me this turned out to be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same error, which was solved by specifying the path for the virtual catalog file (.vrt)

Comment: This worked for me. But what a struggle - I typically use filename like `aux` or `aux.vrt`, but that gives me the same ERROR (Ubuntu 20.04). The change to other informal filename (like `anything.vrt`) made the trick.

Comment: I had the FlushCache() error when specifying the VRT be output to a different directory from the input rasters. I didn't receive an error when outputting the VRT to the same directory as the input rasters.

Answer (score 1):

Error of FlushCache is most likely a path error. You have to check for errors like the path preceding the filename does not exist, another file with the same name exists etc.

In general, it will be an error caused by something not related to gdal itself, but common errors of I/O.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it arrives when I have already a file with the same name. 
When I deleted the file, no more error.